# why doesn't this gcd method work?

Tags: java

I have to write an applet in java calling gcd method and shows the output in showStatus.
This is what i have done so far but when i give the two numbers , the return value is only the second number.can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

any help would be much appreciated.

```
package gcd;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gcd extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
   JLabel promptLabel1,promptLable2;
   JTextField inputField1,inputField2;


  public void init(){

   Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

promptLabel1 = new JLabel( "Enter first number: " );
 promptLable2 = new JLabel( "Enter second number: " );
inputField1 = new JTextField( 10 );
 inputField1.addActionListener( this );
inputField2 = new JTextField( 10 );
  inputField2.addActionListener( this );
 container.add( promptLabel1 );
  container.add( inputField1 );
 container.add( promptLable2 );
  container.add( inputField2 );

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

 int num1 = Integer.parseInt( actionEvent.getActionCommand());

 int num2 = Integer.parseInt( actionEvent.getActionCommand());

 showStatus( "Great Common Divisor is " + gcd( num1,num2 ) );

}

   public int gcd (int num1,int num2){

  while(num1!=0 && num2!=0){
     int temp = num2;
      num2 = num1%num2;
      num1 = temp;
  }
  return num1+num2;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code step by step to understand why this is happening?

Comment: unfortunately i'm a beginner in java.i'm not familiar with netbeans .how can i debug it step by step?u mean using breakpoints???

Comment: (1) select the first line of the method (while(...)) and press CTRL+F8 to create a breakpoint (2) run the file in debug mode with CTRL+SHIFT+F5 (3) enter your numbers and click the button (4) run line by line using the commands in the debug menu (or using the provided shortcuts)

Comment: once you do that you can inspect the values of the variables (by hovering the mouse on the variable or looking at the variables window) and check if the code does what you think.

Comment: the gcd method works well.i debugged that.perhaps sth is wrong with my actionperformed method.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint in the actionPerformed method to check when it is called. Your ActionListener is on the text fields - so I suppose everytime you type something the actionPerformed method is run. If the text field is empty `Integer.parseInt` will throw an exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(inputField1.getText());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(inputField2.getText());
```

Get the text input from the boxes.

Comment: actually i did this.but it just shows zero.i'm sure the gcd method works well.what am i suppose to do now?

Comment: what numbers you added? For me it works perfect. Add number 1 and number 2 than press enter

Comment: in my program it shows 9. Can you post your full refresh code again please

Comment: it just worked.thanks a lot! but can you explain to me what happened?

Comment: You have two input fields inputField1 & inputField2. With the getText() Method you get the text from it.